# Is there any method to find out the display-changing events of android smartphone?

Tags: java, android, events, touch

I'm a student of Yonsei graduate school, Korea.

I want to make a simple application that measures an time interval - between

touching the screen and display-updating.

I found that following method catch the touching event.

```
      public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

            super.onTouchEvent(event);

             if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ){
                        ...
```

Now I'm searching the Android APIs, but I coudn't find the method which catches

display-updating event. If you have any information about this problem,

please show mercy to me. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "display-updating event"? Do you mean when the screen is drawn?

Comment: For example, when I touch the screen in a drawing application, then a point is displayed out. I want to know that point-updated time or event.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a [`ViewTreeObserver.onDrawListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnDrawListener.html) to a view in your Activity's content view. You can make a class that implements the that interface. When you get the touch event, call a method on your draw listener to record the time of the next draw event.

```
private MyDrawListener myDrawListener = new MyDrawListener();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(...);

    findViewById(...).getViewTreeObserver().addOnDrawListener(myDrawListener);
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    super.onTouchEvent(event);
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        myDrawListener.recordNextDrawTime();
    }
}

public static class MyDrawListener implements ViewTreeObserver.OnDrawListener {
    private boolean recordNextDrawTime;

    public void recordNextDrawTime() {
        recordNextDrawTime = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw() {
        if (recordNextDrawTime) {
            Log.d("MyDrawListener", "Draw time = " + System.currentTimeMillis());
            recordNextDrawTime = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm trying to apply your suggestion.